# Plot 2 line graphs on a common Y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below dataset:

I am trying to plot LOS and UCL on the same graph sharing the same Y Axis and I need [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqkPj.png)to change the limits of the Y axis should be dynamic. The issue is the second line is not correctly plotted against the Y axis.

> ```
> orderno   LOS Moving Range    LCL UCL
> 1 7.313873776 0   -0.913600998    19.359629
> 2 15.54207077 8.228196989 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 3 9.792033819 5.750036947 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 4 4.244835588 5.54719823  -0.913600998    19.359629
> 5 9.013500345 4.768664756 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 6 6.264738986 2.748761358 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 7 12.0482677  5.783528714 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 8 5.156349619 6.891918081 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 9 11.12905351 5.97270389  -0.913600998    19.359629
> 10    7.689381194 3.439672315 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 11    6.420359658 1.269021535 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 12    13.652095   7.231735346 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 13    11.17130802 2.480786982 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 14    11.04367016 0.127637864 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 15    6.804112643 4.239557515 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 16    7.148401019 0.344288376 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 17    11.51509024 4.366689225 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 18    10.13792628 1.377163962 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 19    10.07211623 0.065810049 -0.913600998    19.359629
> 20    8.301095504 1.771020729 -0.913600998    19.359629
> ```

```
library(ggplot2)
LOS<-dataset$LOS
Order<-dataset$orderno
UCL<-dataset$UCL
LCL<-dataset$LCL

ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = Order, y = LOS,colour='blue')) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min(LOS)-3, max(LOS)*1.3))+
    geom_line() +geom_point()+guides(colour= FALSE)+
    geom_line(aes(x = Order, y = UCL,colour='deeppink3'))+geom_point()+guides(colour= FALSE)
```

When i used the following code, the UCL line is on the top edge of the graph.

I expected the both lines to follow the  Y axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may avoid confusion if you don't define the x,y in the `ggplot` command, but do it later in the geom_line and geom_point for each of the lines you want.

It is more efficient if you restructure the data in "long" format. If you don't want all lines, then some could be filtered out with `filter(variable == "LOS"|variable == "UCL")`

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataset <-
  read.table(text = "
orderno   LOS Moving_Range    LCL UCL
1 7.313873776 0   -0.913600998    19.359629
2 15.54207077 8.228196989 -0.913600998    19.359629
3 9.792033819 5.750036947 -0.913600998    19.359629
4 4.244835588 5.54719823  -0.913600998    19.359629
5 9.013500345 4.768664756 -0.913600998    19.359629
6 6.264738986 2.748761358 -0.913600998    19.359629
7 12.0482677  5.783528714 -0.913600998    19.359629
8 5.156349619 6.891918081 -0.913600998    19.359629
9 11.12905351 5.97270389  -0.913600998    19.359629
10    7.689381194 3.439672315 -0.913600998    19.359629
11    6.420359658 1.269021535 -0.913600998    19.359629
12    13.652095   7.231735346 -0.913600998    19.359629
13    11.17130802 2.480786982 -0.913600998    19.359629
14    11.04367016 0.127637864 -0.913600998    19.359629
15    6.804112643 4.239557515 -0.913600998    19.359629
16    7.148401019 0.344288376 -0.913600998    19.359629
17    11.51509024 4.366689225 -0.913600998    19.359629
18    10.13792628 1.377163962 -0.913600998    19.359629
19    10.07211623 0.065810049 -0.913600998    19.359629
20    8.301095504 1.771020729 -0.913600998    19.359629",
             sep = "",
             header = T)

# your example data
LOS<-dataset$LOS
Order<-dataset$orderno
UCL<-dataset$UCL
LCL<-dataset$LCL

# dataset %>% 
ggplot(data = dataset) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min(LOS)-3, max(LOS)*1.3))+
  geom_line(aes(x=orderno, y=LOS), color = "blue") +
 geom_point(aes(x=orderno, y=LOS), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(x = orderno, y = UCL),colour='deeppink3')+
  geom_point(aes(x = orderno, y = UCL),colour='deeppink3')
```

[image]

```r
# more efficient with restructured data
dataset %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -orderno) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(orderno, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red", "blue", "deeppink3", "deeppink3"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>